# Access: Report vs Export to XML

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

From my Access DB, I need to build up a document that will be automatically generated on the closure of a certain form.

The document will contain the data of the table as each simple report. But the document must contain other things:

- First Page with some text and images
- Table of Content
- A couple of paragraph of fixed text

In the table, there are also some attachments that are Visio flows. It would be great also to have them in the document, for example as an image at the end of each record.

To do this, is it more suitable build up a **Report** or **Export the data to Word**? What do the best practices advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an OLE object to display files within your Access Report.

You can get fairly flexible with an Access report but Word will have more options for formatting etc